# What is correct, "in-stock" or "on-stock"?

Tags: word-choice, grammaticality, prepositions

Do we have products in stock or on stock?

Answer (score 18):

The correct phrase is *in stock*. No hyphen.

Answer (score 5):

It should be

> Do we have products *in stock*?

where *in stock* functions as an adjective. If products are not *in stock* (*available*), then they are *out of stock*. When these adjectives precede the nouns they modify, they are compounded as *in-stock* and *out-of-stock*:

> - How many candles do we have *in stock*?
> - How many *in-stock* items have expired?
> - The online store displays mostly *out-of-stock* merchandise.

Note that there also exists the phrase, *on the stocks*, which means *in progress/in the making*:

> - Plans to introduce better products are *on the stocks*.

Answer (score 0):

Products can be "in stock", "on hand", or "on the shelf". All these have the same meaning.

Comment: Ask an auto dealer whether he has a certain model "on the shelf"...

Comment: An appropriate change would be "on the lot" or "on the floor".