# "While (the) stock(s) last(s)" (also, "out of stock" and "in stock")

Tags: word-usage

Which of these is/are correct and why?

1. *while stocks last* (as in e.g. *Offer/promotion valid while stocks last*)
2. *while stock last*
3. *while stock lasts*
4. *while the stocks last*
5. *while the stock last*
6. *while the stock lasts*

(To be more specific, let's say the offer/promotion is "5 apples for £2" at a supermarket.)

I was pretty sure only 1 is correct but [various](https://forum.wordreference.com/threads/while-stock-s-last-s.2214095/) [discussions](https://hinative.com/questions/18612130) [elsewhere](https://www.tolearnenglish.com/forum/lire.php?num=6&msg=62362) [seem](https://zh.hinative.com/questions/18612130) [to](https://www.facebook.com/primeenglishlearningcentre/photos/a.10151974332689989/10153117890059989/) have different opinions. So I was hoping to get a more definite and definitive explanation here.

Note: It seems this is a mainly BrE expression (AmE would instead use *while supplies last*).

---

If I'm correct about only 1 being correct, then how is this consistent with our use of the phrases

7. *out of stock*; and
8. *in stock*?

Shouldn't these instead be

9. *out of stocks*; and
10. *in stocks*?

(Maybe 9 and 10 are also acceptable? Or maybe 7 and 8 are just idiomatic expressions/set phrases that can't be varied?)

(Possibly related: [1](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/14441/what-is-correct-in-stock-or-on-stock), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/578448/why-is-of-present-for-out-of-stock-but-not-in-stock).)

Comment: (2) and (5) are ungrammatical (an uncountable noun can't take a plural verb). The others are possible, though _While stocks last_ is the normal British idiom.